# Python multiprocessing list of locks

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm using the `multiprocessing.Array` module to share a very large Array across all my child processes.
The array can be variable length.

I need to synchronize access in every element in the array. So, I do not want to block write operations when two different indexes are written separately. I think this will occur if I use the default (lock = True) in `multiprocessing.Array`.

Is there any way to have a lock/mutex for each variable in the array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to modify elements separately, why don't you use a list of [``Value``s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) instead? Each ``Value`` has its own lock.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi But let's say I do not know the number of values that I want. i.e an array. I might need a thousand variables, or I might need a billion. But the access to each variable in the array needs to be synchronized.

Comment: @SrjanJoshi Was that comment in response to my comment?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ohh I think I get what you mean. I could just make a list of `Value`s and pass that list into the function. I just wrote a dummy code and it worked. Haha lol. Didn't know why I did not think of that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MisterMiyagi said I could just pass a list of [`Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)s to the function. Below is a dummy code

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes


def calc_square(numbers):
    for idx, n in enumerate(numbers):
        numbers[idx] = (idx)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [multiprocessing.Value('d', 0.0) for i in range(100)]
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = calc_square, args = (numbers,))

    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The child process will update each value and it can be synchronized.